# Inner join error in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, inner-join

I am trying to get the count of *keys* from table *tb2* by joining on the column *join_id*.

This is the query I am trying with:

```
SELECT b.key, COUNT(*) 
FROM tb1 AS a 
INNER JOIN tb2 AS b
WHERE(a.DATE BETWEEN '2017-05-01' and '2017-05-30') AND a.DESC1 = 'payment 
  method' AND a.DESC IN ('automobiles')
  AND a.join_id = b.join_id
GROUP BY b.key;
```

I get the SQL state: 42601 and Error code: -104 error. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Am I missing something here? Don't you need an `ON a.join_id = b.join_id` after the `INNER JOIN tb2 AS b`. So it should look like this. `INNER JOIN tb2 AS b ON a.join_id = b.join_id` and remove `AND a.join_id = b.join_id` in the `Where` clause. If it's DB2 explicit syntax, then I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

You have a "1" instead of "a" as the alias of table a

You also need the ON clause after the join if you use this syntax (you could have the join in the where but then you need a comma instead of the INNER JOIN statement.

```
SELECT b.key, COUNT(*) 
FROM tb1 AS a  
INNER JOIN tb2 AS b ON a.join_id = b.join_id
WHERE(a.DATE BETWEEN '2017-05-01' and '2017-05-30') AND a.DESC1 = 'payment 
  method' AND a.DESC IN ('automobiles')
GROUP BY b.key;
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have changed it, still it gives the same error

Comment: @user3447653 -- did you also fix the 2nd issue mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

1. Its not a good idea to use Key word for column name (in you case : Date and Desc )
2. May be your Date column is a timestamp, in this case try to use Date function
3. You have forgotten then clause on into join
4. You have not space between 'where' and '(a.DATE'

try this :

```
SELECT b.key, COUNT(*) 
FROM tb1 a INNER JOIN tb2 b ON a.join_id = b.join_id
WHERE Date(a.DATE) BETWEEN '2017-05-01' and '2017-05-30' 
AND a.DESC1 = 'payment method' 
AND a.DESC  = 'automobiles'
GROUP BY b.key
```